# ffmpeg on windows mobile with C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, ffmpeg

I need to work with **FFmpeg** for **windows mobile** with **C#**, in fact I want build player for *.m4b,.m4a* files. I know that the **TCPMP** is exist, but I want to make my own.
So I want to use **.Net**, and I have some questions:

1. If I use some **C# FFmpeg wrappers**, for example TaoFramework, will it work on windows mobile(in case if I use **FFmpeg lib compiled for windows mobile**)?
2. In FFmpeg wiki I found this

> Once you have compiled, or downloaded,
>   the Windows DLLs for FFmpeg, you can
>   use .Net Platform Invoke (PI) to
>   access the functions in the libraries
>   libavformat and libavcodec.
>   [Link to source...](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/wiki/index.php?title=C_Sharp)

But I don't know how can I use it? I tried to make it with dll that I had downloaded from http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/autobuilds/. Maybe I need to compile ffmpeg by myself for this option?

And last question is - what is libavcodec? When I downloaded shared build, I got avcodec-52.dll, avfilter-1.dll, ffmpeg.exe, but I coudn't find libavcodec.dll, or it's just alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of questions here and a load of things that you need to understand.

First of all, the actual player core logic itself will almost certainly need to be in native code to prevent the possibility of a Garbage COllection (GC).  During a GC, all managed threads are suspended, and when playing video or audio, that's a problem.

So right off the bat this means that if you want your app to be in managed code (which is fine), then you're going to need a hybrid solution. This means you need to understand, and for this application undrstand quite well, how native code works and how managed code interoperates with native code.

Now if there are existing FFmpeg libraries out there (I'll take your work for it, I know nothing of FFmpeg) then the first thing you have to do is determine if they have versions compiled specifically for Windows CE.  If they do not, you will have to determine how difficult it will be to make that port, and the fact you're asking this question leads me to believe that doing a port of that magnitude is going to be very difficult for your current skill set.

If they do have a build for Windows CE then you need to understand what the programming interface for it is.  If it happens to be C++ classes, then you can't directly call that from managed code, so you have to write, in native code, a "shim" library that exposes straight C entry points and that will make all of the C++ allocations and calls for you.

Once you have all of that done, you can then look at the task of calling either the shim or the librariy's C interface from managed code via Platform Invoke.

Basically you have a lot of work to do and there isn't any definitive article I can point you to that will walk you from one end to the other.  Here are a few links to get you started though.  If you *fully understand* every one of these, then you will probably have the proper knowledge to write a wrapper around an existing implementation (not necessarily to write the player core implementation itself).

- [An Introduction to P/Invoke and Marshaling on the Microsoft .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx)
- [Advanced P/Invoke on the Microsoft .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446529.aspx)
- [Marshalling Types During Platform Invoke (P/Invoke) on the Microsoft .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446538.aspx)
- [Writing Unmanaged Functions for Microsoft .NET Compact Framework-based Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446571.aspx)
- [Marshaling data in the Compact Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/marshalling-data-in-cf.aspx)
- [A simple example of complex marshaling](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2007/06/08/ASimpleExampleOfComplexMarshaling.aspx)
- [Recording and Playing Sound with the Waveform Audio Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446573.aspx)